# Is it possible to mirror text in react-native?

Tags: react-native, internationalization

I'm adding right-to-left (RTL) support to my RN app. In this app, I have included a typeface font file which contains vector icon images. Each icon corresponds to a character code.

I render my icons using the RN text component, like this:

```
 return <Text>{"\uE3B2"}</Text>
```

Some of these icons have directional meaning, and therefore, should be mirrored horizontally when using a RTL language.

The RN [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps) suggest using a scaleX transform to flip images. This works for images, but not for text components that contain icons like described above. I know that I can simply swap the icon to one that has the opposite direction, but I'm trying to find a better solution than that.

Does anyone know if there is a way to mirror a text component horizontally at runtime to accomplish this effect?

Answer (score 19):

Yes ! it is possible for the text /View component, oh, and scaleX is deprecated

```
<Text style={{transform: [{rotateY: '180deg'}]}}>This should be flipped</Text>
```

Comment: Hmm I just tried that and it doesn't seem to be working.
As far as I can tell from the Typescript declarations for <Text />, it doesn't support any of the transform styles.

Comment: That's really weird.. are you using the latest version of react native ?  i CAN se the text filpped in the screen , and it's available in the latest docs [the one you showed up are from 2016] . Are you using IOS? check this fix https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16366

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can apply this to mirror a text component:

```
transform: [{ scaleX: -1 }]
```